# How to work around IE10 flexbox overflow bug

Tags: css, internet-explorer, flexbox, internet-explorer-10

With this structure

```
<div id="twitter">
  <div class="info">
    <div>
      <span>Tweets</span>
      <span class="count">561</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span>Followers</span>
      <span class="count">250</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span>Following</span>
      <span class="count">129</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this CSS

```
#twitter {
  width: 220px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #10A4FA;
}
.info {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.info span {
  font-size: 14px;
}
.info span.count {
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

it displays like the top in IE11 and most browsers, but like the bottom in IE10 (emulated in IE11 devtools)

[image]

[Here is a codepen showing it.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ORJwVA?editors=1100)

I've tried adding `max-width: 100%` to `.info`, various `box-sizing` and `flex-grow` things, and adding the ms prefixes but I can't get it to behave in IE10

Comment: Could you add a <br> after your span? I've also found that sometimes I have to set widths on the flex items which add up to 100% to get them working in old IE.

Comment: @kthornbloom adding `<br>`s does kind of work (it seems to have the same effect as `.info span { display:block; }` for some reason) but the positioning of the 3 divs is slightly different as a result

Comment: IE10 supports a previous version of the flexbox spec and requires *vendor prefixes*. See here for details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35137869/3597276

Comment: @Michael_B Yes, but that doesn't seem to be the problem here. If you turn on autoprefixer in Codepen, it doesn't fix it. I've updated the question to clarify this

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
.info > div{
 width: 33.33%
{
```

its because flex width to items does support in IE10. so give it width to 33.33%

Comment: This does kind of work, but it changes the positioning of the 3 divs slightly (compared to how it should normally look in eg IE11)